# Why can't I build my vite assets on my virtual private server?

Tags: npm, build, vite

I am setting up a server on an Ubuntu 20.4 VPS with vite and php.

When I try to build my assets on the server it freezes on `transforming (x): node_modules/path/to/module` and its always a different module.

I tried to recreate the issue on my desktop by running these steps:

1. Clone repository
2. `cd repository`
3. `npm i`
4. `npm fix audit`
5. `composer install`
6. `npm run build` (which calls vite build & vite build -ssr)

That works perfectly fine with no errors and within seconds.

Doing the EXACT same thing with the same npm and node versions on my vps leads to the aforementioned issue. I am extremely confused to why this behavior is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I figured it out.

My VPS had 1 gb of ram allocated which wasn't enough to finish the build process before it got killed.

After allocating 4 GBs it finished in an instant similarly to my local machine.

Solution: Allocate more resources